# How do I run code multiple times in a single run?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in java using eclipse. Here i am calculating average utilization of machines. I want to run this code 20 time and then need to take average of this code. Is it possible to do the same. I am using simple formula for calculations:

```
AU=ActCPUtime/(max*3);
```

So each time when the program runs it fetches the value for max and ActCPUTime variables.
I need to run this program for different values of ActCPUtime and max which i can get in different run. Please help me out with this. Thank You

Comment: Do some research by looking up what a loop is in java.

Comment: Use arrays, store your results in an array while looping; and then after the array is filled up with running times do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** -

Suppose we have Class-A and Class-B

//class A body (where your logic stored in a method named calculateAU() )

```
public double calculateAU()
{
double AU=ActCPUtime/(max*3);

return AU;
}

//Method for max calculation

//Method for ActCPU time calculation

//Finished Class A
```

Now how to fetch and average your values -

Class-B body -

```
A test=null;
{
double AU;
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
test= new A();
AU+=test.calculateAU();
}
AU/=20;     //Hurray :)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The actual difficulties i am facing in calculations of 20 values of ActCPUtimes and max values see my code.

Comment: The actual difficulties i am facing in calculations of 20 values of ActCPUtimes and max values see my code. Once i take this code in loop that will will me array index out of bound exceptions. Please see and help me out with this.

Comment: I f i understood correctly you need to do this - 
Create a Class/function to calculate AU. 
now inside a  loop call that class or function and gather values, then calculate the average. 
+ there is no code over here. :-D